# Passing a group of words as a bash script argument

Tags: bash, arguments

I would like to pass in a group of words as an argument to a bash script. It seems that when I want to print the argument, only the first word of the group is printing.

These are my scripts the first just assigns a group of words to a variable and passes the variable to another script. The second just prints the variable which it was passed.

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
GC='lblue, lblue, lgrey, lred, lred'
./script2.sh $GC
```

script2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "$1 \n"
```

This is the current result of my script when I run it

```
./script.sh 
lblue,
```

I would like the script to output this instead

```
lblue, lblue, lgrey, lred, lred
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the variable in double quotes to preserve white spaces - it is one of the best practices in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
GC='lblue, lblue, lgrey, lred, lred'
./script2.sh "$GC"
```

---

In script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "$1 \n" => when $GC was passed without double quotes, shell treated them as separate words and $1 was the first word
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass array:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=("$@")
gc=$(IFS=, ; printf "${a[*]}"| sed 's/, */, /g' )
printf "${gc[*]} \n"
```

**input**

```
gc=(red green blue)
./script.sh ${gc[*]}
```

**output will be:**

```
red, green, blue
```